# Flyway check if database exists and was baselined in java

Tags: java, mysql, flyway

I'm trying to use Flyway in my web application. I've read the docs, but couldn't find an answer to the following question:

Is it possible to check if a database was `baselined` before running `migrate`?

The web application already uses a large database. So I need to run `baseline` for it. I want the application to run `baseline` and/or `migrate` on startup. The database should be created if it doesn't exist and it should be `baselined` if it exists, but wasn't `baselined` before.

I already added 3 SQL files to the migration package:

```
V4_0_0__schema.sql
V4_0_1__index.sql
V4_0_2__initial_inserts.sql
```

I want to do it like this:

```java
DataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
String[] locations = {"path/to/location"};

Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setCleanDisabled(true);
flyway.setLocations(locations);
flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);

if (databaseExists()) { // how to determine that the db already exists?
    if (databaseWasBaselined() == false) { // How to check this?
        flyway.setBaselineVersion(MigrationVersion.LATEST); // will this set the version to 4_0_2?
        flyway.baseline();
    }
}
flyway.migrate();
```

I need a little help to do it the right way. I hope, that someone can point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `baselineOnMigrate` option as documented on the [Flyway site](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate):

> Whether to automatically call baseline when migrate is executed against a non-empty schema with no metadata table. This schema will then be baselined with the `baselineVersion` before executing the migrations. Only migrations above `baselineVersion` will then be applied.
>
> This is useful for initial Flyway production deployments on projects with an existing DB.
>
> Be careful when enabling this as it removes the safety net that ensures Flyway does not migrate the wrong database in case of a configuration mistake!